# How do I find out the attributes of a terraform object?

Tags: terraform

I'm creating a Terraform file, and something is obviously wrong,

```
Error: Incorrect condition type

  on ssh.tf line 47, in locals:
  47:   is_generated = data.local_sensitive_file.public_key ? true : false
    ├────────────────
    │ data.local_sensitive_file.public_key is object with 4 attributes

The condition expression must be of type bool.
```

How do I find out what the attributes of `data.local_sensitive_file.public_key` are though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `local_sensitive_file` here is a data source, you can assume that its attributes are the attributes defined by the provider that this data source belongs to, which is [`hashicorp/local`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs).

At the time of writing [the documentation for `local_sensitive_file`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/data-sources/sensitive_file) says that it has the following attributes:

- `filename`
- `content`
- `content_base64`
- `id`

Provider documentation is typically the best place to find out about attributes of a resource type because it'll also tell you what these attributes represent, in addition to their names.

Not all objects you'll encounter in Terraform will originate in providers though, so a more general answer that will work for any object you can refer to in an expression is to run `terraform console` and then ask it for the type of the value in question:

```
> type(data.local_sensitive_file.public_key)
object({
    content: string,
    content_base64: string,
    filename: string,
    id: string,
})
```

Unfortunately for a resource (either a `resource` or `data` block) it won't yet have a known type until it's been created or read for the first time, and so if your configuration isn't valid then you would need to make it valid enough to run `terraform apply` successfully before you could use this technique. But for objects that are defined within the Terraform configuration itself, rather than by external operations that haven't run yet, the console is a useful way to inspect data and data types.

Comment: your answer is better than mine, thanks for coming in after with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the keys with

```sh
terraform show -json |
  jq '.values[].resources[] | select(.address=="data.local_sensitive_file.public_key").values | keys'
```

Which should return,

```json
[
  "content",
  "content_base64",
  "filename",
  "id"
]
```

Alternatively you can look up [`local_sensitive_file`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/data-sources/sensitive_file) in the docs.

Comment: It doesn't work: first item is null. Try it yourself!